# Why are we allowed to have a final main method in java?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, final

Can anyone tell me the use of making main method as final in java.

while this is allowed in java

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {  



}
```

I dont see any use of making it final. anyways it is static so we can not override it.

Comment: Unless you're using this `main` method for anything other than starting your app, there's absolutely no reason to make it `final`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `final` to a static method can actually make a difference. Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C.main(args);  // Will invoke B.main
    }
}
```

Adding `final` to `A.main` would prevent accidental hiding of `A.main`. In other words, adding `final` to `A.main` guarantees that `B.main` is not allowed, and that `C.main` therefore prints `"A"` as opposed to for instance `"B"`.

> *Why are we allowed to have a final main method in java?*

Beside the above corner case, adding `final` to a static method doesn't make much difference, so I don't see a big point in adding a rule for disallowing it.

More information available here: [Behaviour of final static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743715/behaviour-of-final-static-method)

Comment: `final` will prevent hiding a `static` method.

Comment: I tried adding final to A's main method, the class is now having compilation error in Class B - **Cannot override the final method from A**. I am using Java 1.7. Is this answer valid?

Comment: @gyan, I don't follow you. Which part do you think is invalid?

Comment: @aioobe the current given code is good and compiling. But if I try `public static final void main(String[] args)` in class A; my eclipse is showing compilation error in Class B's main method. The error is - **Cannot override the final method from A** . Because of the error, I am not able to validate your point - *so that C.main in fact prints "A" instead of "B".* Please let me know, if you still do not get it, I will share a screenshot of my eclipse.

Comment: @gyan, I understand what you're saying, but I'm asking which part of the answer you think is invalid. The answer clearly states that *Adding final to `A.main` would prevent accidental hiding of `A.main`* which seems to be precisely what you've discovered.

Comment: Because of the error, I am not able to validate your point - *so that C.main in fact prints "A" instead of "B".*

Comment: If you add `final` to `A.main` you can't have `B.main`, which makes sure `C.main` in fact will print `"A"`. I've reworded the answer slightly to clarify. I don't think the answer is invalid in any way.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. Now it is more clear. It means adding final to main method at any class will not allow to create a main method in the child classes into the inheritance hierarchy.