# Can final inner classes be re-initialised?

Tags: java

I have below code, where I have a final inner class.

So as per final it should not allow to re-assign it a value. But it still does. Please explain:

```
public class POJO {

    public final String vNew;

    public POJO () {
        vNew="hello";
    }

    final class abc {
        String name="abc";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        POJO vPOJO = new POJO();
        POJO.abc in=vPOJO.new abc();  
        System.out.println(in.name);
        in.name="World";
        System.out.println(in.name);
        in=vPOJO.new abc();
        System.out.println(in.name);
    }    
}
```

Output is

```
abc
World
abc
```

The code **POJO.abc in=vPOJO.new abc();**  and **in=vPOJO.new abc();** is re-assignment isn't it.

Just not sure as it uses the handle of outer non final class, makes it work.

Comment: duplicate of [Use of final class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[If a class is `final`, it just means it can't be extended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).

If you want to prevent reassignment, make the *variable* final.

```
POJO vPOJO = new POJO();
final POJO.abc in = vPOJO.new abc(); //Notice the final
System.out.println(in.name);
in.name = "World";
System.out.println(in.name);
in = vPOJO.new abc(); // Compilation error
System.out.println(in.name);
```

And of course, if you want to prevent reassignment of the `name` *field*, make the field `final` instead. If you did that,

```
in.name = "World";
```

would no longer compile.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)) describes various uses of `final`. Summed up, they are:

- `final` classes

  - can't be extended
- `final` methods

  - can't be overridden
- `final` variables/fields

  - can't be reassigned

There is also the issue of [`static final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743715/behaviour-of-final-static-method) methods.

Comment: you are very correct, I got confused between variables and classes... this was so brain freeze of me...

Answer (score 1):

The **class** is final:

```
final class abc {
    String name="abc";
}
```

but **not** the field. And of course that is the same as with "normal" classes - it prevents subclassing that inner class. That is all there is to this!

To prevent re-assining that value; you do what you do for normal classes as well:

```
class abc {
  final String name="abc";
}
```

make the **field** final!

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works) for further reading what *final* is about, depending on the **context**.