# Do Java 8 Compilers optimize Static Methods on an Interface as "Final?"

Tags: java, javac

My specific question is: do compilers inline the Static Final Interface code within other compiled methods?  I've been out of the loop for a while on this type of optimization, and wanted to know if this is still performed.

Comment: static and final are mutually exclusive anyway. You cannot override a static method, so it's always final.

Comment: Are you asking if they're inlined?

Comment: Considering the tiny amount of optimization `javac` does, I wouldn't count on it. Why don't you fire up `javap` and see.

Comment: download a java decompiler and check yourself if final was added.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Correct.

Comment: Behaviour of final static method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743715/behaviour-of-final-static-method @daniu While they can't be overridden, they can be hidden. `final` prevents this. I would think that this implies that final is NOT added by the compiler to a non-final class, but could possibly be added to a final class.

Comment: @Kayaman Will do so unless someone knows offhand.

Answer (score 1):

`javac` will not `inline` *anything* - it does very little optimization anyway. The `JIT` might inline that indeed, depending on the fact if that method is hot enough and can be inlined and no threshold has been reached.