# Can Java's main() method be declared final?

Tags: java

In Java, which declaration of the `main()` method is valid? 
We commonly use  `public static void main(String[] arr){}`, but what I want to know is: can the `main()` method be declared final?

```
final public static void main(String[] arr) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Compiler says yes

Comment: You can also use vararg `main(String... args)` or have it throw any Exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can mark `main` `final`.

While it is possible, it is **not really meaningful**. `final` methods can not be overriden. But static methods cant anyways, since they are not inherited when extending.

---

### Hiding

However, it has an effect when actually hiding by introducing a method with the same name in an extending class. See [Behaviour of final static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743715/behaviour-of-final-static-method).

A contrived example to this:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from A");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from B");
    }
}
```

Suppose you are calling those methods manually:

```
A.main(null);  // "Hello from A"
B.main(null);  // "Hello from B"
```

Note that Java also allows to call `static` methods from instances:

```
A a = new A();
a.main(null);  // "Hello from A"

B b = new B();
b.main(null);  // "Hello from B"
```

But what if you reduce the view of a `B` object to an `A` object:

```
A bAsA = new B();
bAsA.main(null); // "Hello from A"
```

And this might be surprising. Since, usually, it will take the method from the actual instance, which would be `B`. But that only applies when you are actually overriding methods, which is never the case with `static` methods.

Marking `main` as `final` will result in **no subclass being able to hide your method** anymore. That is, `B` will not be able to declare a method `main` anymore (with the same signature). The above code will then not compile.

Answer (score 4):

> The short answer is Yes.

You can declare main method as final. without any compile error.

```
public class Car {
    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("yes it works!");
    }
}
```

> Output

**yes it works!**

But when we use inheritance concept. we cannot declare the main method as `final`. if it is parent class.

```
public class Parent {
    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}
```

> Output: Cannot override the final method from Parent .

But you can declare the final method in child class main method.

```
public class Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}
```

> Output: 
> Parent
> Child

Answer (score 0):

There is no such restriction in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-MethodModifier) although I expected it to be sincr such combination of modifiers is meaningless (in almost all cases as @Zabuza noted). In fact, there are only 3 restrictions on applying modifiers

I

> It is a compile-time error if the same keyword appears 
>   more than once as a modifier for a method declaration, or
>   if a method declaration has more than one of the access 
>   modifiers `public`, `protected`, and `private`

II

> It is a compile-time error if a method declaration that 
>   contains the keyword `abstract` also contains any one of 
>   the keywords `private`, `static`, `final`, `native`, `strictfp`, or 
>   `synchronized`.

III

> It is a compile-time error if a method declaration that 
>   contains the keyword `native` also contains `strictfp`.

Comment: It is not completely meaningless though, it has indeed an effect. A subclass can not declare such a method anymore (not speaking of overriding). So you can kind of *lock* a method signature. I admit that this is an extremely rarely useful tool though.

Comment: @Zabuza did not think about such usage, indeed.