# If cannot static methods to override, then why them not keep as final?

Tags: java, static, overriding, final

I'm new to java and I have a question.

In java not allow to override the static methods. I think the reason is static method does not belong to any instance of the classes. But however, under the **inheritance**, we can obtain properties and methods (except private members) from another class. Then according to the inheritance, we should be able to inherit the static methods also. Then why they cannot be overridden? Ok. If they cannot override, why we cannot keep the static methods as **final** (because final methods cannot be overridden).

what is the reason for this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743715/behaviour-of-final-static-method

Comment: static methods don't belong to an object but to a class. Thus they're not inherited and don't need to be explicitly final exact the same way as interface methods don't need to be marked as public.