# final class with final static methods redundant

Tags: java, static-methods

I have a bunch of static final methods within a final class:

```
public class final Util{

    private Util{}

    // do I need the keyword final when the class is already final
    public static final util1{..}
    public static final util2{..}
    public static final util3{..}

}
```

I know, instance methods are implicitly final when its class is final. However, is this the case also for static methods?

Comment: Static methods are always final (you cannot override them in child classes)

Comment: Static methods (without final) can be overriden (can be hidden).There is a difference of making static methods final or not final.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was not aware of this fact. Thanks! (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1743715/112968)

Comment: Hi, yes they are final as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final classes cannot be extended in the first place, so it does not matter whether or not their methods are marked as `final`.

For example, this will fail:

```java
final class Util {
}
class Extra extends Util {
}
```

> error: cannot inherit from final Util
> class Extra extends Util {

Comment: Static methods (without final) can be overriden (can be hidden).There is a difference of making static methods final or not final

Comment: @nimo23 but you cannot extend the class, so there is nowhere to "hide" them from. You are never able to generate a conflict, because final classes cannot have subclasses.